# Marking circle centres with + and x

Tags: plotting, marker

This is probably quite a simple question, but I am looking to plot these circles and mark their centres with + and x markers, not the standard dot-like marker. Any help would be great! Thanks!

```
outercircle = Graphics[{{Black, Thick, Circle[{0, 2}, 2]}}];
innercircle = Graphics[{{Black, Dashed, Thick, Circle[{0, 1}, 1]}}];
Centre1 = Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Black, Point[{0, 2}]}];
Centre2 = Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Black, Point[{0, 1}]}];
Show[outercircle, innercircle, Centre1, Centre2]
```

Comment: Do you want a line figure, a polygon one, or a font glyph for each marker? Each is treated differently when aligning, scaling, exporting, and so forth. Fonts have been the least satisfactory to me, though MaTeX generally works well; however, others might have different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ocircle = Circle[{0, 2}, 2];
icircle = Circle[{0, 1}, 1];
Graphics[{
  {Black, Thick, ocircle}
  , {Text[Style["x", 20, Bold, Red]
    , RegionCentroid@ocircle]}
  , {Black, Dashed, icircle}
  , {Text[Style["+", 15, Bold, Blue]
    , RegionCentroid@icircle]}
  }
 ]
```

---

[image]

Comment: I like your answer more than mine,. I did not know about `RegionCentroid`. This is better than what I did by manually shifting the center.

Comment: Thanks. Wait a while longer and there will be other answers to choose from.

Comment: If you want a more symmetric "x" marker, instead of one that looks like a letter of the alphabet, consider using `\[Cross]` instead of `x`.

Comment: Or draw lines explicitly as `Graphics` primitives.

Answer (score 5):

```
ocircle = Circle[{0, 2}, 2];

icircle = Circle[{0, 1}, 1];
```

To center the text objects at desired positions, you can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html) to transform font glyphs to graphics objects and use them as [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html)

```
{tx, tplus} = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text[Style[#, 12, Bold]], _Text, 
     BaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], #2], 
     ImageSize -> 15] & @@@ {{"x", Red}, {"+", Blue}};


Graphics[{
  {Black, Thick, ocircle,
   Opacity[.5], Gray, AbsolutePointSize @ 25, Point @ RegionCentroid @ ocircle},
  {Black, Dashed, icircle, 
   Opacity[.5], Gray, AbsolutePointSize @ 25, Point @ RegionCentroid @ icircle}, 
  Inset[tx, RegionCentroid @ ocircle], 
  Inset[tplus, RegionCentroid @ icircle]}]
```

[image]